# Why does $P\left(\frac{1}{x^* - X}\leq x\right) = P\left(x^* - X\geq \frac{1}{x}\right)$ hold?

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Verify that the distribution function of $X$ is in the domain of attraction of $G_\gamma$ with  $\gamma<0$ if and only if $\bar{X}= \dfrac{1}{x^*-X}$ is in the domain of attraction of $G_{-\gamma}$, where $x^*= \sup\{x, F(x)<1\}$. In order to do so, I need to derive a relation between $F(X)$ and $\bar{F}(X)$. In the book that I'm using the following derivations are performed:
\begin{align*}
    \bar{F}(x) = P(\bar{X}\leq x) &= P\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x^* - X}\leq x\bigg)\\
 &= P\bigg(x^* - X\geq \dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)\\
&= P\bigg(X\leq x^* - \dfrac{1}{x}\bigg) = F\big(x^* - \dfrac{1}{x}\big)
\end{align*}
I don't understand why the second equality sign holds. By definition $x^*$ is positive, but I don't see why $x^* - X$ has to be positive. If $x^* - X$ is negative, then I don't see why we can say $\dfrac{1}{x^* - X}\leq x \Rightarrow x^* - X \geq \dfrac{1}{x}$.

**Question:** Why does it hold that $P\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x^* - X}\leq x\bigg) = P\bigg(x^* - X\geq \dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)$?

Comment: Look at the definition of $x^*$. It is the supremum of all of the $X$ with a particular property, so it is certainly at least as large as all of those $X$. Is it possible that $X>x^*$?

Comment: What is $G_{\gamma}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general $a\ge b$ if and only if $\frac{1}{a}\le \frac{1}{b}$, as long as $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.  In case either inequality has a probability, the other has the same probability.

The only possible problem is if $a$ or $b=0$